# Memory upgrade for MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking to upgrade my 15'' 2011 MBP from 4 GB to 8 GB. The memory upgrade on the Apple Store is 200$, apparently it can be done for ~100 $ quite easily.

I've seen this 2x8GB kit from Crucial: [Crucial 2x4GB memory kit](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=MacBook%20Pro%202.0GHz%20Intel%20Core%20i7%20%2815-inch%20DDR3%29%20Early-2011&pl=Apple&cat=RAM).

Do you think it's a good choice ? Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Crucial kit is one of the better ones out there.  I've used their modules in the past.  However, on my new MBP, I decided to get the 8 GB from Apple.

I'd go with the Crucial if you want good quality and great value.

Here is a video showing installation
http://www.ramfor.com/ram-memory/apple-macbook-pro-early-2011-crucial-memory-upgrade/